# Azure Logic connector to Databricks notebook

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-logic-apps, azure-databricks

i am trying to call databricks notebook from Azure Logic app & there is one parameter(projectcode) which i need to pass from logic app to notebook, It's dynamic parameter, Is there any mechanism  to get/catch this dynamic parameter value on databricks notebook.

Example:  **project_id = dbutils.widgets.get("Projectcode")** # need to get/catch "**Projectcode**" value from logic app

[image]

Rather than hard coded need to get Projectcode value dynamically

Comment: You may check out this article which describes: [Create Azure Logic Apps Custom Connector For Azure Databricks](https://medium.com/@poojaanilshinde/create-azure-logic-apps-custom-connector-for-azure-databricks-e51f4524ab27)